# is there any way to draw canvas images with relative positioning

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was trying to have a wheel on a canvas with multiple equal size segments similar to wheel of fortune. On the circumference of the wheel, i.e arc of each segment, I want to have an image attached that needs to rotate with wheel.

I was able to draw multiple images, but they have be positioned with respect to (0, 0) (top-left) of the canvas only. Is there any way to position them relative to some point instead of the origin? In my case the centre of the circle (300, 300)?

Comment: Which method did you use to draw these images?

Comment: [`context.translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate)

Answer (score 1):

You can translate the origin of your canvas by calling `.translate(x, y)` method of the canvas drawing context; in your example both x and y would be 300.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations for more information on canvas transformations.